# Should a Kafka consumer consume from all partitions to get a complete message?

Tags: apache-kafka

I was going through Kafka, and I understand that topics will be partitioned into ordered sequences of partitions.

Since topics are partitioned, should the consumer consume from all of the partitions, in order to get a complete message? If this is so, whose responsibility it is to make complete message out of all messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each complete message is written, in its entirety, into a single offset in a single partition.  Just by reading a single message from any one partition using any of the available consumer API's, you're assured of getting the whole thing.

See the [Kafka site](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html) for more info

Comment: Thanks Chris for quick response. Is there any documentation with clear example i can take a look at ? I am going through the kafka documentation, i am getting lost after few paragraphs